# Temperature of homogenous mixture (sourdough!) considering air temp

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm trying to write an app that helps bakers calculate what's known as the "final dough temperature" (FDT). The idea is that a recipe will tell the baker that the FDT needs to be 24°C (or whatever) and, while they have no control over the temperature of the flour, starter, salt, etc, they *do* have control over the water temp, so you adjust that as needed to arrive at the desired FDT.

There's an accepted way of doing this in the baking world but it's notoriously inaccurate. The "formula" is so goofy that I'm not even going to list it here but you can Google it.

I'm not a physicist by any stretch, but it seems to me that if you know the mass and temps of all the constituent ingredients, then you can pretty easily calculate what the water temp needs to be to achieve a given FDT.

ie starting with:

$$FDT = \sum_{i=0}^n m(ingredient_i) / totalMass * T(ingredient_i)$$

You can then break out and solve for the water ingredient. I hope that's straightforward enough (and sorry if my notation is off… I'm not that familiar with physics notation).

That's fine in a vacuum, but what I'm not sure about is air temperature. In practice, the baker mixes all the ingredients together by hand or with an electric mixer (which also adds heat due to friction, but let's not deal with that now), and while doing so there must be some influence on the temperature of the mixture from the surrounding air temperature. I *think* this would be non-negligible.

Given the mass and density of the dough mixture, the amount of time the dough is mixed, and the ambient air temperature, is there a way to calculate, or even approximate, the effect on FDT?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_heat_capacity

Comment: Someone has voted to close this as an engineering question. I suppose that deriving a useful formula *is* engineering. OTOH, explaining the physics relevant to that formula *should* be on-topic here, IMHO.

Comment: @PM2Ring Then the OP should edit the question to ask about the relevant physics.